# Print Popup is showing blank screen in pos js

Tags: javascript, odoo-11

I have a custom widget. In that custom widget I am showing pos receipt of an old order. On clicking the print Receipt button in the top corner I have to get a pop of print screen. For that I am using the below code.

But I am getting a blank pdf screen in the popup eventhough I am getting the receipt in pos screen.

window.print();

Answer (score 0):

I have got the print using the below code;

```
var printContents = document.getElementById('printareas').innerHTML;
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
```